# Is there a way to define a member lambda to use `this`?

Tags: c++, lambda

There are many questions on lambda capture, but I thought it would be a little helpful to novices in a similar situation.

I want to achieve functionality similar to below (which doesn't make sense):

```
struct Person{
    std::string sName;
    std::string(*introduce)();
};
int main(){
    Person p1{
        "John",
        []()->std::string{
            return "my name is " + this->sName; // I wish this `this` indicates `p1`, which does not.
        }
    };
    std::cout << p1.introduce() << std::endl;
}
```

My workaround:

```
struct Person{
    std::string sName;
    std::string(*introduce)(Person*);
};
int main(){
    Person p1{
        "John",
        [](Person* pPerson)->std::string{
            return "my name is " + pPerson->sName;
        }
    };
    std::cout << p1.introduce(&p1) << std::endl;
}
```

But I think there might be a better way. Can anyone please advise?
Thank you.

Edit: The reason I used a function pointer as a member, instead of a normal member function, is to customize each lambda for each `Person` object.

Comment: Write a wrapper `std::string introduce() { return introducePtr(this); }`. Also `Person* pPerson` -> `Person& pPerson` because `this` can't be null. Would then be `introducePtr(*this);`, of course.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a callback from the outside that uses a member of the class? I can't imagine any use for that where a simple method wouldn't be a viable option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I want to use different lambdas for each object(`Person` in this example).

Comment: @Axalo Thanks. Could you elaborate a little more on why using `Person&` is better than `Person*`?

Comment: @starriet So you don't have to check for null in the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a helper member method that calls the function member variable.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Person{
    std::string sName;
    std::function<std::string(Person const&)> introduce_fn{ [](Person const&){ return ""; } };

    auto introduce() const -> std::string { return introduce_fn(*this); }
};

int main(){
    Person john{ "John", [](Person const& p) -> std::string { return "my name is " + p.sName; } };
    Person cowboy{ "Cowboy", [](Person const& p) -> std::string { return "Yee-haw, my branding says " + p.sName; } };
    Person moana{ "Moana", [](Person const& p) -> std::string { return "Mele Kalikimaka, I am " + p.sName; } };
    std::cout << john.introduce() << "\n";
    std::cout << cowboy.introduce() << "\n";
    std::cout << moana.introduce() << "\n";
}
```

**Footnote**, replying to comment.

Simple function pointers work too.  Having `std::function` does allow for closure lambdas.  Was not clear if such stateful lambdas was wanted in the original question.  If such capability is unnecessary, simple function pointers are (in my opinion) a better solution.

ISO C++ Core Guidelines [F.60](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-ptr-ref) recommends to prefer `Person const*` over `Person const&` as the lambda's parameter in the case of:

- when "no argument" (`nullptr`) is a valid option

For the example provided in the original question, there does not appear to be any situation where the lambda would ever be called with a `nullptr`.  Hence, I opted to use a const-reference parameter rather than a const-pointer parameter, which also means the lambdas do not have to check for `nullptr` and handle them appropriately - and that means less code, and less chance of forgetting to check for `nullptr`.

Comment: Just for future myself) 1. of course, this can be done using simple function pointers, too. 2. `introduce_fn{ [](Person const&){ return ""; } };` works like a default lambda, and this kind of "default" lambda can be achieved with simple function pointers, too. 3. Think about `Person*` vs `Person&`, as commented in the question by @Axalo.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to be able to change that function, I would create a method, too. This method invoke the function you set as member. Anyway I would suggest you to check if polymorphism may fit your needs. With polimorphism you might create a base class or structure with an abstract method and than override it in derived classes and structure to change it s behavior. Hope to be helspful

**EDIT**

Here is an example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    virtual std::string introduce() {
        return std::string("Hi, I'm ") + this->name;
    }
};

struct Doctor : public Person {
    virtual std::string introduce() {
        return std::string("Hi, I'm Doctor ") + this->name;
    }
};

struct Professor : public Person {
    virtual std::string introduce() {
        return std::string("Hi, I'm Professor ") + this->name;
    }
};

int main() {
   Person *d = new Doctor; d->name = "Gennaro";
   Person *p = new Professor; p->name = "Rocco";
   std::cout << d->introduce() << std::endl;
   std::cout << p->introduce() << std::endl;
   std::cout << dynamic_cast<Person*>(d)->introduce() << std::endl;
   std::cout << dynamic_cast<Person*>(p)->introduce() << std::endl;
}
```

*OUTPUT*

```
Hi, I'm Doctor Gennaro
Hi, I'm Professor Rocco
Hi, I'm Doctor Gennaro
Hi, I'm Professor Rocco
```

Using polymorphism you will be able to have istances which structures have the same parent class, so you can treat them as they are all of the same type. But they will act differently basing on how you implement each class. Anyway when passing function as parameter is useful have little bit of aknowledge of functional programming. Usually many problems can be converted in FP style improving readability and flexibility, I would take a look. Good programming ;)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please demonstrate a simple example of using polymorphism regarding this question?

Comment: That's compile-time polymorphism, unlike the runtime polymorphism in the question.